# How install IIS 7 to Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7

I need to set up a server to run ASP.NET application on it.
But I can not install IIS7 can be an article "Step by Step"?

I like doing everything as [here](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-install-iis7-on-windows-7.aspx), but the transition to localhost do not show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the web platform installer - see [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/616/using-the-microsoft-web-platform-installer/) it will allow you to very easily download and install the latest IIS7 release or if you prefer the IIS7 Express version

Answer (score 0):

To install IIS:

1. In Windows, access the Control Panel and click 
   Programs.
2. In the Programs window, click Network and Internet.
3. Select the Internet Information Services (IIS)
       check box, then click Ok.
4. To learn how to use IIS,
       you can view the documentation at
       http://localhost/iishelp/iis/misc/default.asp.